# CoreWCF - Return Custom Soap Fault with nil Faultstring

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, corewcf

We have an existing SOAP API implementation we are migrating to CoreWCF, where we are returning a SOAP fault with a faultstring with nil="true". Our vendor is using this response to perform some error handling business logic. We need to continue to return this.

e.g

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-206" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsu:Created>2023-03-13T17:41:03.762Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2023-03-13T17:46:03.762Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:soap11Env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">soap11Env:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In the code, if I throw a FaultException, like so:

```
throw new FaultException();
```

Then I will receive a SoapFault response like:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2023-03-13T20:58:09.310Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2023-03-13T21:03:09.310Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
        <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason.</faultstring>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Note the faultstring has some placeholder messaging injected.

If I throw a FaultException like:

```
throw new FaultException(string.Empty);
```

I will get a response like:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2023-03-13T20:58:09.310Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2023-03-13T21:03:09.310Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason.</faultstring>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

An empty faultstring. It's not quite what we're looking for.. I'd like to not have to change the vendors client code.

Any ideas on how to return a soap fault where the faultstring is nil="true" like in first example?

many thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, if you add xsi:nil="true" and make the property value  null, how do you get a soap fault?

Comment: Thanks @jiayao.  How do I add xsi:nil="true" attribute when throwing the FaultException? I have tried a few different ways as shown above. CoreWCF doesn't seem to allow it.

Comment: Does this result change when remove `xsi:nil="true"`?

Comment: @jiayao, sorry I don't understand your question/suggestion. In the above examples we are using CoreWCF and in the C# code, throwing "FaultException". Using this method, I am trying to generate a SoapFault with a faultstring with nil="true" as the faultstring attribute, like shown in the first SOAP example. Any thoughts?